# jQuery multiple events with live()

Tags: jquery

I was under the impression that since I'm using the current version of jQuery, I could bind multiple events to live(). I'm trying to achieve a simple effect: fade down a picture when hovering, and then fade back up when mousing off of it. I have:

```
$(".previews").live("hover", function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('normal', .3); 
        },function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('normal', 1);
    });
```

From every example I've seen, this should work. Right now, when I mouse over, it fades down,  but not up again.

Comment: Can you give a complete example (with HTML) that's not working? Ideally via [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont think you can use `live` with `hover` like this,use something like

```
$(".previews").live({
        mouseenter:
           function()
           {
                 $(this).fadeTo('normal', .3); 
           },
        mouseleave:
           function()
           {
              $(this).fadeTo('normal', 1);
           }
       }
    );
```

`hover` is just short hand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
hover: function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
}
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/event.js#L994-996

Comment: +1 excellent answer, included explanation, and code resource. Nice.